# Normal and Poisson Approximation

Tags: probability

Suppose $10$ percent of households earn over $80,000$ dollars a year, and 0.25 percent of households earn over $450,000$.

A random sample of $400$ households has been chosen. In this sample, let $X$ be the number of households that earn over $80,000$, and let $Y$ be the number of households that earn over $450,000$. Use Normal and Poisson approximation, whichever is appropriate in either case, to ﬁnd the simplest estimates you can for the probabilities $P ( X ≥ 48)$ and $P ( Y ≥ 2)$.

Comment: For the very rich, use Poisson $\lambda=1$.

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange!

Answer (score 0):

The probability $P(Y\ge 2$ is calculated easier using the poisson-distribution because only $2$ values have to be calculated, if you consider $P(Y\ge 2)=1-P(Y=0)-P(Y=1)$.

$P(X\ge 48$, however is calculated easier with the normal distribution because otherwise, you would have to add many probabilities.

Comment: Can you explain it more specifically?

Comment: Suppose, $X$ is binomial distributed with parameters $n$ and $p$. $X$~$B(n,p)$ , $n\ =\ $ number of trials $p\ =\ $ probability of success

Comment: If $n$ is large (often, the rule $npq>9$ is used, where $q$ denotes the probability of a failure), then $X$ is approximately normal distributed with mean $np$ and variance $npq=np(1-p)$.

Comment: If $p$ is small (and ideally $n$ large) , then $X$ is approximately poisson-distributed with $\lambda=np$

Comment: The normal distribution is continous ($X$ can be any real number) and useful, if the interval is large. The Poisson-distribution would be cumbersome in this case because it is discrete. The only possible values are $0,1,2,..$

Comment: If only a few values have to be calculated, the normal distribution would be goos as well, but the Poisson-distribution is easier, especially, if you want to calculate, for example $P(X=21)+P(X=27)+P(X=33)+P(X=44)$.